# Codebehind does not set <asp:label> Text in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to design a form using VB.Net for WebForms. I have been following the following link [My label's text isn't changing on page_load asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552908/my-labels-text-isnt-changing-on-page-load-asp-net). But the solution there is not working for me. I already have `Handles Me.Load` defined for my `Page_Load` event handler, however the result is a "blank" page, with the HTML output below.

**form.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="form.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyApp.form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Label id="vcode" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

**form.aspx.vb:**

```
Imports System.Web

Public Class form
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        vcode.Text = "Why not?"
    End Sub

End Class
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Test
</title></head>
<body>
    <span id="vcode"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect it has to do with the `Inherits` attribute, but if I take out `Page_load` from that class definition, I get an error:

> Statement is not valid in a namespace

I also tried setting the `AutoEventWireup` attribute on the page to true, but no change.. still blank label.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you put a break point on the page load event? Does the debugger step into the method?

Comment: no! it doesn't... hmmmmm

Comment: a message shows "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version" -- what does that mean?

Comment: That means the browser is running the previous version of your web app. Try to recompile the web app.

Comment: if i move the break to the `vcode.Text` line the message also includes "Possible causes include: conditional compilation or compiler optimizations"

Comment: Try right clicking on the project in the soultions tab then clicking "Clean" in the contextual menu. Also try closing and re-opening VS. Some of the temp files for the project may be corrupt.

Comment: hmm cleaning the project revealed another error. I think there are other issues going on and the project is not recompiling properly. i will have to call it a night now but I can use the info you have provded. it makes sense now. thank you!

Comment: Also see...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468852/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-the-source-code-is-different-from-the

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a namespace like so:

```
Namespace MyApp

  Public Class form Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      vcode.Text = "Why not?"
    End Sub

  End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't help, OP already stated this: "I also tried setting the AutoEventWireup attribute on the page to true, but no change.. still blank label."